# Query collection by specific documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing an issue I can't really get my head around and hoped someone here might shed some light -
I've an app with ‘first class’ collection that its documents can be referenced and extended by another different collection.
it is something like a fundamental items that are built in the app and users are able to extend or override its fields such as price, description, status etc'...
the issue I'm facing is querying the fundamental collection and get only the items that are extended elsewhere.

It is important to query the fundamental items themselves for the sake of querying/sorting them always by popularity, relevance or whatever will be important in the future.
any word of advice out there??
Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you just want to query the extended collection.  By your definition, only documents there are extending the base collection.  If this is not what you're looking for, then please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish by actually showing data that you're trying to query and explain the result of a query that you're trying make.

Comment: @DougStevenson it is important to query the original collection as I might need basic name / rating sorting and these fields only exist on the original collection

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to do this with a single query, since a query can only returns results from a single top-level collection.  You can't merge or join the documents from both collections in a single query.

What you will probably end up doing is performing a single query from the base collection to find your result set, then individually get each possible matching extension from the other collection.

Or, you will have to add a third collection which stores the merged documents from each collection into a single collection that can be queried on its own.  It is not uncommon to duplicate data in NoSQL databases for the purpose of special queries.

Comment: I see, the most important idea behind this issue is to keep the option to query the base collection because its documents might have dynamic fields such as 'ratings' that I will need to sort the queries by. if I will duplicate that 'rating' field for example I will have to always delegate changes throughout all extended documents for all users. I don't feel it's a good practice :(

Answer (score 0):

When using firebase or any nosql solutions you need to design your collections depending on how you will use the data, in your case you will need a third collection that stores what you will fetch or you have to store a copy of the data in the fundamental collection